# "Застанческое"

Tags: словообразование

Ситуация следующая: кого-то застали. Иронично описывая ситуацию, можно ли назвать это "застанческим положением"? Нет ли в русском языке препятствий для создания такого прилагательного?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В русском языке нет такого прилагательного. И образовать такое прилагательное тоже нельзя. Оно трудно произносится, неясное.

Answer (score 3):

Образовать прилагательное "застанческий" нельзя.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Суффикс СК (также ЕСК, ЧЕСК, ИЧЕСК, НИЧЕСК и др.) используются для образования относительных прилагательных от существительных (не от глаголов). Следовательно, сначала надо от глагола "застать" образовать существительное, а такого существительного нет.

Для сравнения: захватить - захват - захватнический.

Comment: А где можно подробно прочитать об этих нюансах?

Comment: Я пользуюсь книгой: Ефремова Т.Ф. "Толковый словарь словообразовательных единиц". Там в алфавитном порядке представлены все приставки и суффиксы, определена их семантика, схемы словообразования, приведены примеры.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

Можно. В основе существительного слово стан. Представьте себе: в стане есть руководство, порядок. За станом - беспредел, мерзость. Вот такое положение за станом.

Comment: Полагаю, в вашем примере речь может идти о "застановом положении", но не о "застанческом".

Comment: Согласен. Но, полагаю, что автор этого выражения воодушевился бытующими выражениями типа "повстанческое движение". С другой стороны, есть авторское право конструировать слова и выражения в угоду художественной выразительности изображения конкретной ситуации. Пример: один известный театральный деятель (не помню кто), говоря о поддержании дисциплины в театре изрек: ...начнутся всякие взбутитенивания...  По каким правилам слово возникло? Ясно, что оно произошло от взбучки. Но в быт оно не вошло. Недолго потерлось в театре. То же будет и с "застанческим".